# Saving the amount of time between each time stamp in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working on a python script to get the speed of an object between one point to the next. I have the function already created (see below) and works when I test it, but now that I know it works and want to use it, I hit a road block. I cannot seem to find a way to calculate the time between each point and save it as an array using `numpy`. My file has hundreds of different points.

```
def speed(lat1, long1, time1, lat2, long2, time2):
    distance = haversine_distance(lat1, long1, lat2, long2)  # meter
    delta_time = time2 - time1 # second
    speed = distance / delta_time # speed in m/s
    speed = speed * 3.6 # speed in km/h

    return speed
```

The time stamps are in the following format for each point:

```
timestamp.roundHr
12/8/2009 7:00
12/8/2009 8:00
12/8/2009 9:00
12/8/2009 10:00
```

Comment: Are you trying to take the output of `timestamp.roundHr` and add into a numpy array?

Comment: I want to take the amount of time between each time stamp and put them in their own array.

Comment: Where is `timestamp` coming from, I don't see if in the code you have there.

Comment: timestamp.roundHr is the column which holds all the dates in the file, when I tested the function I just used two different time which made into objects (time1, time2) not the actual file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have timestamp1 and timestamp2. First, create a datetime object with each, and then get the delta time by subtracting one from the other:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

def speed(lat1, long1, time1, lat2, long2, time2):
    distance = haversine_distance(lat1, long1, lat2, long2)  # meter

    # here's the fun stuff
    time1 = dt.strptime(time1, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
    time2 = dt.strptime(time2, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
    delta_time = (time2 - time1).total_seconds() # second

    # continue with the rest of your code
    speed = (distance / delta_time) # speed in m/s
    speed = speed * 3.6 # speed in km/h

    return speed
```

If your list of timestamps contains `n` elements, and you want to compute a different list of `n-1` elements, such that the `i`th element in the new list is the delta time between the `i`th and `i+1`th elements in the old list, then this should work:

```
def computeDeltaTimes(L):
    answer = []
    a, b = itertools.tee(L)
    next(B, None)
    fmt = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
    for start, end in zip(a,b):  # or itertools.izip in python2
        answer.append((dt.strptime(end, fmt) - dt.strptime(start, fmt)).total_seconds())
    return answer
```

Comment: But I am not looking to make an object name for each timestamp, since there are so many, is there another way?

Comment: is there a way to get this to work with numpy? I keep getting "TypeError: must be string, not numpy.ndarray"

Comment: @DeanPickles: unsure. But my code assumes `L` is a list. So, if you are able to cast your numpy array into a list, it should work

Comment: So it works but, sort of. It is not returning unique values for each time. Often in the results it shows that many of the timstamps which can be different in time up to 8 hours are the same in amount of seconds. this is what i did to your code to make it work for me, am i putting something in wrong? def compute_delta_time2(timelist2):
    time2 = []
    a, b = itertools.tee(timelist2)
    next(b, None)
    fmt = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
    for start, end in itertools.izip(a,b): 
        time2.append((dt.strptime(end, fmt) - dt.strptime(start, fmt)).total_seconds())
    return time2

Comment: Do I need to change the a and b values?

Comment: @DeanPickles: This code takes every consecutive pair of timestamps and computes the number of seconds between each pair. From your question, this is what I gathered you wanted. From your most recent comment, this is what it seems to do. I don't understand how my solution differs from what you're looking for. If you could explain it in more detail, I'd be happy to edit my answer

Comment: No bother! I just figured out my problem, it was on my end not your script. Thanks a lot! the script works great!